# Overloading bitshift operator in c++

Tags: c++, arm, operator-overloading, c++14, simd

I want to overload the bitshift operator for a `uint32x4_t` defined on ARM systems in `arm_neon.h`.

```
struct uint32x4_t {
   uint32_t val[4];
};
```

This should be done with a call to a SIMD function, which expects the value to shift and a constant immediate:

```
uint32x4_t simdShift(uint32x4_t, constant_immediate);
```

shift.h

```
#ifndef SHIFT_H
#define SHIFT_H

namespace A {
   namespace B {
      /*uint32x4_t simdLoad(uint32_t*) {
         ...
      }*/

      template<int N>
      uint32x4_t shiftRight(uint32x4_t vec) {
        return vshrq_n_u32(vec,N);
      }
   }
}
uint32x4_t operator>>(uint32x4_t const & vec, const int v) {
  return A::B::shiftRight<v>(vec);
}
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "shift.h"

int main() {
   uint32_t* data = new uint32_t[4];
   data[0] = 1;
   data[1] = 2;
   data[2] = 3;
   data[3] = 4;
   uint32x4_t reg;// = simdLoad(data);
   reg = reg>>3;
   return 0;
}
```

This code produces the error:

> ‘uint32x4_t operator>>(const uint32x4_t&, int)’ must have an argument
>   of class or enumerated type  uint32x4_t operator>>(uint32x4_t const &
>   vec, const int v) {

Is there a workaround to overload `operator>>` for "native" types like `uint32x4_t`?

Edit: I adapted the suggested workarounds, but the error still remains the same :(

Comment: You need to bring the operator into scope; `using namespace A::B;` is an easy fix. As an aside, that `constant_immediate` that `simdShift` expects must be a _constant expression_; a `const int v` parameter is not sufficient.

Comment: @ildjarn But I can't pass an constexpr into a function can I?

Comment: @Hymir : Not as an `int`, no. But you can make it a function template and pass an instance of `std::integral_constant<int>` instead, which will work. You can use variable templates or a UDL to make constructing integral_constant instances legible.

Comment: That is an awesome hint for handling constant_immediate! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An incremental improvement on ErmIg's answer:

```
template<int N>
constexpr std::integral_constant<int, N> i_{};

template<int N>
uint32x4_t operator >>(uint32x4_t value, std::integral_constant<int, N>) noexcept {
    return _mm_slli_si128(value, N);
}

int main() {
    std::uint32_t data[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    uint32x4_t reg;// = simdLoad(&data);
    reg = reg >> i_<3>;
}
```

N.b. I've put `operator>>` in the global namespace; if you want to put it in a different namespace, you'll need to bring the operator into scope before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

"uint32x4_t is a native type, provided by arm_neon.h." (from another comment).

The problem you're facing initially is that C++ uses something called Argument-Dependent Lookup. For `A::B::uint32x4`, C++ would consider `A::B::operator>>(uint32x4, int)`. That is to say, C++ will look in the namespaces of the respective arguments.

Your problem is that `uint32x4` is in the global namespace, and yet you put your `operator>>` in another namespace. That's just wrong. Put it in the correct namespace.

Note that namespaces are one of the two mechanisms provided to avoid name clashes. Overloading is the other mechanism. Namespaces work for all types of names: variables, types, and functions. Overloading only works for functions. But in this case, that's sufficient, as operators are a subset of functions. You won't get a name clash; your `operator>>` overloads with other `operator>>`.

Answer (score 2):

For calling of function with constant immediate (it often meets in SIMD intrinsics) I usually use template function with integer template parameter. The following example is used SSE2 but for NEON it will be similar:

```
template<int shift> __m128i Shift(__m128i value)
{
    return _mm_slli_si128(value, shift);
}

int main()
{
    __m128i a = _mm_set1_epi8(3);
    __m128i b = Shift<2>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how it can be made for C++ operator. Of course, we can create an operator with template argument but it is very inconvenient for using:

```
template<int shift> __m128i operator >> (__m128i value, int shift_)
{
    return _mm_slli_si128(value, shift);
}

int main()
{
    __m128i a = _mm_set1_epi8(3);
    __m128i b = operator >> <2>(a, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The variant inspired by @ildjarn :

```
template<int N> struct Imm {};

#define IMM(N) Imm<N>()

template<int shift> __m128i operator >> (__m128i value, Imm<shift>)
{
    return _mm_slli_si128(value, shift);
}

int main()
{
    __m128i a = _mm_set1_epi8(3);
    __m128i b = a >> IMM(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly the way I implemented it! But I thought an operator>> would be much better to read.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to move the `operator>>` from the `A::B` namespace to the global namespace. If all the other symbols are different namespaces then you just need to qualify them. For example, if `simdShift` is in `A::B` you can still have global `operator>>` like this:

```
uint32x4_t operator>>(uint32x4_t const & vec, const int v) {
    return A::B::simdShift(vec, v);
}
```

But I guess that it were more appropriate to make `operator>>` a member of `uint32x4_t` instead:

```
struct uint32x4_t {
    uint32_t val[4];
    uint32x4_t operator>>(const int v) const;
};

namespace A { namespace B {
/// TODO: Put declaration/definition of simdShift here
}} // namespace A { namespace B {

uint32x4_t uint32x4_t::operator>>(const int v) const {
    return A::B::simdShift(*this, v);
}
```

Or alternatively, as [ildjarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636019/ildjarn) suggested in a comment, pull symbols from the `A::B` namespace into the context where you use them by writing:

```
using namespace A::B;
```

Comment: That looks awesome, but uint32x4_t is a native type, provided by arm_neon.h. Thus I can't simply add the operator>> as a member, can I?

Comment: @Hymir Not as a member, no. But you can define the operator globally for an existing type. If you want it as a member, you would have to wrap `uint32x4_t` in your own type first, and then add the operator to that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If i use it like this:
namespace A{ namspace B {
    template<int N>
    uint32x4_t shiftRight(uint32x4_t vec) {
      return vshrq_n_u32(vec,N);
    }
}
}
uint32x4_t operator>>(uint32x4_t const & vec, const int v) {
    return A::B::shiftRight<v>(vec);
}
and use it like this:
uint32x4_t vec>>3;
I got the same error:
"uint32x4_t operator>>(const uint32x4_t&, int)’ must have an argument of class or enumerated type
 uint32x4_t operator>>(uint32x4_t const & vec, const int v) {"

Comment: @Hymir you can't use a runtime value as a template parameter. Get rid of the template, it is not helping you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know. It isn't a runtime value at all.

Comment: @Hymir: `uint32x4_t operator>>(uint32x4_t const & vec, const int v) { return A::B::shiftRight<v>(vec); }` - the value of `v` is not known until runtime, so it can't be used as a template parameter.